# How to correctly set and use a bullet list in a Powerpoint template?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm currently trying to prepare a slide master for a set of presentations. In the Slide Master, I defined a multi-level bullet list with custom formatting/spacing (for both, Slide Master and the "Title and Content" layout) to look like this:

[image]

However, when I then insert a new slide with content, the format from the template is not applied (while the `First level` string is used):

[image] (Note the round bullet vs. the square bullet above.)

Even worse, when I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right arrow</kbd>, the format is completely screwed up:
[image]

So, my question is: how can I prepare a template/slide master in a way, that I can really use the predefined multi-level bullet style?

Sidenote: I'm using Powerpoint 2010, but have the issue since PPT 2003. I saw it working in corporate templates.

Comment: Have you tried starting with a per-existing template which works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the template I was working with was slightly corrupt. When (in the master view) I deleted the "Content" textbox that I formatted - and reinserted it (clicking `Master Layout` and checking `Text`), the new textbox showed the messed-up formatting that was used as a default. Once I changed this again back to the format I wanted, everything works as expected...